# Best way to remove multiple leading zeros in non-numeric value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was reading about "Best way to remove leading zeros from a non-numeric value in Excel" and I love the solution provided but the issue is that, its only removing 1 zeros from the preceding zero's. I need it to find the zero's and remove them all. So, I used that formula and inserted another if statement like this:

```
=IF( LEFT(S3) = "0", RIGHT(S3, LEN(S3)-1),IF(
    LEFT(S3) = "0",
    RIGHT(S3, LEN(S3)),
    S3))
```

But, it didn't work.

Comment: What will come after the 0, only numbers or text also?

Comment: You have to address maximum length of any String of text, and maximum length of the number without zeros. I see creative solutions, but they are all hypothetical off of your theoretical problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned the maximum number of "0" expected in your alphanumeric value, so, here is an example with a Maximum of 4 zeroes:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,4)="0000",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-4), IF(LEFT(A1,3)="000",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3), IF(LEFT(A1,2)="00",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2), IF(LEFT(A1,1)="0",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1), A1))))
```

This will give you the next result:

[image: delete zeroes]

Of course if your value is numeric a single:

```
=VALUE(A1)
```

will suffice.

Comment: Thank you so so very much fernando for your help. That worked great. Thank you for your assist.

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(IF(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)<>"0",ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))))),LEN(A1))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

It will find the first non `0` and set that as the first character in the MID function.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this small User Defined Function:

```
Public Function nozero(s As String) As String
    Dim l As Long
    l = Len(s)

    If Left(s, 1) <> "0" Then
        nozero = s
        Exit Function
    End If

    t = s
    While Left(t, 1) = "0"
        t = Mid(t, 2)
    Wend
    nozero = t
End Function
```

Comment: And if you add `Option Explicit` to the top your Module, you can use it as a local formula.

Comment: @ejbytes You are correct

Answer (score 0):

Define a name which creates an array of numbers `1:255`

```
seq   refers to:  =ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))
```

Then use this formula entered by holding down <kbd>ctrl + shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=MID(A1,MATCH(TRUE,MID(A1,seq,1)<>"0",0),99)
```

[image]